# PHP-SDK: check if user has authorized my app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using PHP-SDK GraphAPI (not FQL) how do I check if a user has added my Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try GET graph API request to 
/[UID]?field=installed

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`https://graph.facebook.com/ID USER/accounts`

to take all the app installed by a user

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it without using the API.
The user_id is also set from the signed_request if you asked your user to add your app. This will be "visible" then, and if it is not (or doesn't exist) then the user has not added your app.

Comment: That is true. I always show different content and encourage users to add the app or login to app before they can interact with it. This is of course different depending of the purpose of the application.